# How to set particular limit for zooming in bar charts

Tags: ios, swift3, charts

I have created bar charts. when I am trying to zoom the chartview, it is going infinitely.  I need to set particular limits for zooming
I have tried with below function-

```
func chartTranslated(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, dX: CGFloat, dY: CGFloat)
{
    //its getting executed while zooming  
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to limit the zoom:

```
    lineChart.viewPortHandler.setMaximumScaleX(2)
    lineChart.viewPortHandler.setMaximumScaleY(2)
```

Comment: Thank you DevB2F.......i have tried with viewporthandler but its showing as viewportHandler does not found in my view controller..

Comment: What version of iOS-charts are you using?

Comment: chart version 3.0.4... i have attached the link where i get the source https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Above command i have share the github link,same source i have used  In that code for barchart i need to zoom for particular limit.

Comment: I am talking about the code you created, not the code for the library. Can you show the code that gives the error "viewportHandler not found in view controller"? Where did you put the code?